# How can I edit a imported animation?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, import

I'm using Blender to create custom TF2 taunts. Basically it is just an animation. I imported the animation and I wanted to change something. I selected pose editing, then copied and pasted the pose, and after about 8 frames changed the animation. The thing is, that I got the change only on one frame. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert/update a keyframe, do this before moving to another position on the timeline. Once pressed, it will give you a choice of what to record. If you have no scaling, use LocRot.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to edit, one way is to override the key frame with "I" or right click on a parameter and add/replace key, best way is go to graph-editor (click on down-left side of every view and choose) and select the curve of that animation of object, you can select any key and move to see the effect.